# socket is working with heroku perfectly but when i switch to another server is not woking on react native apps but wokis on firecamp

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

the socket is working with  Heroku perfectly but when I switch to another server is not working on react native apps but works on fire camp when I connect with the IP address of the server this will work but I can't use the server IP address.

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
let SOCKET_URL=config.SOCKET_URL;
console.log('SOCKET_URL',SOCKET_URL)
let socket = null;
export function socketDriverInit(userId) {
  socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
    reconnectionAttempts: "Infinity",
    rejectUnauthorized : false ,
    jsonp: false,
    transports: ['websocket'],
    forceNew: true,
    secure:true,
    requestCert: false,
    // rejectUnauthorized: false

  });
  socket.on('status', (text) => {
    console.log('#status',text);
  });
  socket.heartbeatTimeout = 10000; // reconnect if not received heartbeat for 17 seconds
  socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('websocket connected')
      updateSocket(socket,userId)
    });
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    if(!socket.connected){
      console.log('websocket disconnected')
      socket.connect();
      updateSocket(socket,userId);
    }
  });
  return socket;
}
```

Comment: Does the socket get's disconnected or not even connecting?

Comment: it is not response from the server and client from both side